# vue.js passing prop through script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I’m passing a component as a variable through the store e.g.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="store.state.General.body"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import store from "@/store"
</script>
```

Now I was wondering how I would pass the component with props because this is how I’m doing it:

```
<script>
    import Input from "@/components/Input"

    methods: {
        example() {
            store.commit("general_set_modal", {body: Input, title: "New "+page})
    }
</script>
```

it’s being rendered properly, but just lacks the desired props.

Comment: Maybe [dynamic props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props) is what you're looking for? (Look for "pass all the properties")

Comment: @RoyJ Not quite, since I can't exactly use html tags inside the `script` area. I would probably have to assign it like `var input = Input` then have `input` assign the props like `input.prop.example = "this is an example prop"`

Comment: You would make the binding in the `template` area: `<component :is="store..." v-bind="somePropsObjectYouBuilt">`

Comment: @RoyJ The purpose of that component is just to display the component passed in. It's a modal, so I want to be able to throw anything into there and separate the dependencies.

Comment: In your example above, what would be the prop(s) you want passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="store.state.General.body" v-bind="store.state.General.props"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import store from "@/store"
</script>
```

and have the store item look like

```
<script>
    import Input from "@/components/Input"

    methods: {
        example() {
            store.commit("general_set_modal", {body: Input, props: {title: "New "+page}})
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, I must have misunderstood you before. yeah this works great.

Comment: Although I seem to be getting a warning `[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."` even though I'm only calling it as a read.

Comment: I don't have any idea what that's about. There's no watcher in the code samples you included.

Comment: Yeah I don't have watchers implemented either, which is why it's weird. Well the one `watch` that I have is in a completely unrelated file :\ I am accessing the variable through the `prop`

Comment: Vuex maintains a deep watch in [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/strict.html) to catch inadvertent mutations. Maybe that's going on.

Comment: It's definitely caused by accessing the variable through `props`.

Comment: Might be worth a new question. Include the code of the component you're using.